# Choosing the right average method

Tags: mean, types-of-averages

The following tables shows the wall clock times of some programs. So, `A` means the time for one configuration and `B` means the time for another configuration. I also have written the ration of `B/A` which shows B takes less time than A.

```
    A   B   B/A
M1  1   1   1
M2  4   2   0.5
M3  35  9   0.257
M4  298 67  0.224
M5  18  6   0.333
M6  6   3   0.5
```

Now, I want to find the average of reductions. I can do that with three different ways:

1- `Arithmetic mean of B/A  = 0.469218068` Since B/A is a ratio, I don't think this is a good way to measure the average.

2- `Harmonic mean of B/A = 0.367272358` That makes sense because harmonic means is used for ratios.

3- Finding the arithmetic means of A and B separately and then dividing AVG(B) to AVG(A).

```
AVG(A) = 60.33333333
AVG(B) = 14.66666667
AVG(B)/AVG(A) = 0.243093923
```

My question is, which of second and third methods are preferred and makes more sense?

Comment: A piece of an answer:  The data here are rather skewed.  If you want to mitigate the effects of this skew, you might use something like the harmonic mean or geometric mean, or perhaps another measure of central location.  For these data, the results for "*B/A*" is relatively similar for the geometric mean, Huber M estimator, and median.